# In Singapore, is there a weekly/monthly transit pass foreign tourists can buy?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, singapore

I'll be visiting Singapore for 5 weeks in Dec/Jan, and the place I'm staying is out in the boonies (Seletar) so I'll probably be taking the LRT/MRT/buses a lot. When I did a quick Google, I was able to find the 1-3 day Singapore Tourist Pass, which would be prohibitively expensive to buy ten of for a month's stay, and the Adult Monthly Travel Card, which is available only to citizens and permanent residents.

Is there a longer-duration transit pass available to foreigners? In case it matters, I'm a 19-year-old US citizen with no student ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will depend of course on how much you travel every day, but if you commute twice a day, your cheapest option will be to buy a rechargeable card ([EZ-Link](http://www.ezlink.com.sg/)) and just pay the fare. Single fares while using this card are capped somewhere around 2.70 S$ a trip. The fare is [distance-based](https://www.sbstransit.com.sg/transport/trpt_fares_adults.aspx), and transferring from bus to train or from one bus to another bus will still count as one trip. So assuming you travel twice a day, the maximum you spend in a week is going to be not more than 30 S$, very likely even much less.

One tool I like to use to find the fares for trips is the website [gothere.sg](http://gothere.sg/maps#q:seletar%20camp%20to%20bugis) you can enter your start and destination (if you can't find it, just use the postal code) and it will tell you travel time and price. There's other websites with similar functionality, but I find that this one has the most accurate travel times.

Comment: +1. Since the Travel Pass costs $120, and the average short MRT hop is under $1, you have to travel a lot and for long distances for it to pay off.

Comment: Almost all the residents go for the prepaid cards. Its much cheaper, unless you are constantly traveling. It will be cheaper than paying by cash by a lot.